# Web scraping the IIS based website

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am using R to webscrape a table from [this site](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/data-analysis-documentation/federal-employment-reports/historical-tables/total-government-employment-since-1962/).

I am using library `rvest`.

```
#install.packages("rvest", dependencies = TRUE) 
library(rvest) 
OPMpage <- read_html("https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/data-analysis-documentation/federal-employment-reports/historical-tables/total-government-employment-since-1962/")
```

I receive this error:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). It's not necessarily the end of the road, but certainly a roadblock.

Answer (score 13):

It's [forbidding you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) from accessing the page because you have `NULL` in the `user-agent` string of your headers. (Normally it's a string telling what browser you're using, though some browsers let users spoof other browsers.) Using the `httr` package, you can set a `user-agent` string:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/data-analysis-documentation/federal-employment-reports/historical-tables/total-government-employment-since-1962/"

x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Gov employment data scraper ([[your email]])'))
```

Wrapped in a `GET` request, `add_headers` lets you set whatever parameters you like. You could also use the more specific `user_agent` function in place of `add_headers`, if that's all you want to set.

In this case any `user-agent` string will work, but it's polite (see the link at the end) to say who you are and what you want.

Now you can use `rvest` to parse the HTML and pull out the table. You'll need a way to select the relevant table; looking at the HTML, I saw it had `class = "DataTable"`, but you can also use the SelectorGadget (see the `rvest` vignettes) to find a valid CSS or XPath selector. Thus

```
x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node('.DataTable') %>% 
    html_table()
```

gives you a nice (if not totally clean) data.frame.

**Note:** Scrape responsibly and legally. Given that OPM is a government source, it's in the public domain, but that's not the case with a lot of the web. Always read any terms of service, plus [this nice post on how to scrape responsibly.](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/ethics-in-web-scraping-b96b18136f01)

Answer (score 0):

Your format for `read_html` or `html` is correct:

```
library(rvest)
lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
lego_movie <-      html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
```

But you're getting a 403 because either the page or the part of the page you're trying to scrape doesn't allow scraping.

You may need to see `vignette("selectorgadget")` and use selectorgadget in conjunction with rvest:

http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

But, more likely, it's just not a page that's meant to be scraped. However, I believe Barack Obama and the new United States Chief Data Scientist, DJ Patil, recently rolled out a [central hub](http://www.data.gov/) to obtain that type of U.S. government data for easy import.

Comment: `?html`: "`html` is deprecated: please use `read_html()` instead."

Comment: _please_ don't use IMDB as a ref example for scraping. You're 100% asking folks to be unethical and subjecting them to potential legal action. I care not whether pkg vignettes or RStudio uses it. It's wrong.

Comment: @hrbrmstr That's a pretty radical statement for not giving any reasoning behind it. Not to mention they're open to having their data downloaded for analysis and provide plain text dumps of it and their engineers have helped people with their IMDB bots. They say they don't mind scraping, but broken bots that don't do a good job of it cause headaches.

Comment: _"Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below."_  / _"e do allow the limited use of robots and crawlers, such as those from certain search engines, with our express written consent."_ unless I can't read English. I highly doubt you have such a document (their consent) handy.