# could not read webpage with read_html using rvest package from r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the location of product reviewers from amazon. For example, this webpage

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AH55KF4JK5IKKJ77MPOLHOR4YAQQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8][1]

I need to get `HAINESVILLE, ILLINOIS, United States`

I use rvest package for webscraping.

Here is what I did:

```
library(rvest)       
url='https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AH55KF4JK5IKKJ77MPOLHOR4YAQQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8'
page = read_html(url)
```

I got error like below:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.
```

But, the following works:

```
con <- url(url, "rb")
page = read_html(con)
```

However, with the page I read, I could not extract any text. For example, I want to extract the location of the reviewer.

```
page %>%
    html_nodes("#customer-profile-name-header .a-size-base a-color-base")%>%
    html_text()
```

I got nothing

```
character(0)
```

Can anyone help figure what I did wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How did you select "#customer-profile-name-header .a-size-base a-color-base"
Did you use the Selector Gadget?
This might help: https://www.queryxchange.com/q/27_51801321/getting-xml-nodeset-0-when-using-html-nodes-from-rvest-package-in-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# get url
url='https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AH55KF4JK5IKKJ77MPOLHOR4YAQQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8'

# open page
con <- url(url, "rb")
page = read_html(con)

# get the desired information, using View Page Source
page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath=".//script[contains(., 'occupation')]")%>%
  html_text() %>% as.character() %>% str_match(.,"location\":\"(.*?)\",\"personalDescription") -> res

res[,2]
```

Comment: have you checked this code? for instance, why put double quotes around the package name in library call? The function `as_character` is missing a library call? When i execute your code, I get this error, `Error in as_character(.) : could not find function "as_character"`

Comment: @captcoma  your code works after replace `as_character` with `as.character(.)`. Thanks a lot for you answer! I have two question:   1.  how to quickly find the element I need after I use view source. Lots of text.....  2.  why `read_html` does not work directly on the url?

Comment: thank you for your hints, I corrected my answer. 
1: I used the search function (ctrl +s) and looked for the desired information
2: probably because of NULL in the user-agent, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690914/web-scraping-the-iis-based-website

Comment: @captcoma would you mind having a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158332/how-to-make-html-node-work-for-this-website) where I raised a similar issue? That would be very helpful. Thanks so much