# How to pull a product link from customer profile page on Amazon

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get the product link from a customers profile page usign R's RVEST package

I've referenced various questions on stack overflow including here([could not read webpage with read_html using rvest package from r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064293/could-not-read-webpage-with-read-html-using-rvest-package-from-r)), but each time I try something, I'm not able to return the correct result.

For example on this profile page:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AETT6GZORFV55BFNOAVFDIJ75QYQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8

I'd like to be able to return this link, with the end goal to extract the product id: B01A51S9Y2

[https://www.amazon.com/Amagabeli-Stainless-Chainmail-Scrubber-Pre-Seasoned/dp/B01A51S9Y2?ref=pf_vv_at_pdctrvw_dp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01A51S9Y2)

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(httr)
library(rvest)

# get url
url='https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AETT6GZORFV55BFNOAVFDIJ75QYQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8'
x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'test'))
page <- read_html(x)

page %>%
  html_nodes("[class='a-link-normal profile-at-product-box-link a-text-normal']") %>%
  html_text()

#I did a test to see if i could even find the href, with no luck

test <- page %>%
  html_nodes("#a-page") %>%
  html_text()

grepl("B01A51S9Y2",test)
```

Thanks for the tip @Qharr on Rselenium. that is helpful, but still unsure how to extract the link or asin. library(RSelenium)

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), port = 4574L, chromever = "77.0.3865.40")
rd <- driver[["client"]]
rd$open()
rd$navigate("https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AETT6GZORFV55BFNOAVFDIJ75QYQ/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_gw_btm?ie=UTF8")
prod <- rd$findElement(using = "css", '.profile-at-product-box-link')
prod$getElementText
```

This doesn't really return anything

Added the get attribute href, and was able to get the link

```
prod <- rd$findElements(using = "css selector", '.profile-at-product-box-link')

for (link in 1:length(prod)){
  print(prod[[link]]$getElementAttribute('href'))
}
```

Comment: Where is B01A51S9Y2 product ID in https://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/amzn1.account.AETT6GZORFV55BFNOAVFDIJ75QYQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_gw_tr?ie=UTF8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That info is pulled in dynamically from a POST request the page makes that your rvest initial request doesn't capture. This subsequent request returns in json format the content governing asins, the products links etc.....

[image]

You can find it in the network tab of dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd>. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page then examine network traffic:

[image]

It is not a simple POST request to mimic and I would just go with RSelenium to let the page render and then use css selector

```
.profile-at-product-box-link
```

to gather a webElements collection you can loop and extract href attribute from.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @QHarr, RSelenium is very nice, but I'm struggling pulling the link or asin. I've tried various combinations of link, css, class, etc. See updated code above.

Comment: I haven't used RSelenium as doesn't seem to want to set up on my system but from other languages I would expect the following: you need a wait condition for all elements to be present based on that css selector; the method should be plural e.g. rd$findElements  and then you would need to extract the href attribute not the .text property in a loop over the returned webElements collection. Looks like method getElementAttribute(attrName) for getting href, the method for collection is findElements.

Comment: I can't see anything immediate about wait for presence of all elements in [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf.)  I could run something in python just to see what conditions are needed if that helps.

Comment: You could always start with a hard coded wait to see if principle works overall.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr !. That was the trick, getElementAttribtute('href'). 
I has a lot of issues getting RSelenium to work as well. Had to go through several posts and change various settings. Ultimately the Chromever option solved it.