# How to make "html_node" work for this website?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I have an issue webscraping this [website](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/index_include.en.html). If I try the "conventional" way, it works fine like in the code below:

```
base_url <- "https://www.ecb.europa.eu"
year_urls1 <- paste0(base_url, "/press/pressconf/", 2000:2008, "/html/index_include.en.html")

scrape_page <- function(url) {
  Sys.sleep(runif(1))
  
  html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(url), ".doc-title a"), name = "href")
}

all_pages1 <- lapply(year_urls1, scrape_page)
all_pages1 <- paste0(base_url, unlist(all_pages1))
```

But now let's assume for x reasons that `read_html`doesn't work on the url directly. To circumvent the problem I use `url` but then this seems to create problems with `html_nodes`. This problem is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064293/could-not-read-webpage-with-read-html-using-rvest-package-from-r). However, I don't manage to get around with it. See the code below for only one case:

```
html_nodes(read_html(url(year_urls1[1, "rb")), ".doc-title a") # I get an empty object
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this? You would make my day!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried `html_nodes(read_html(url("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/index_include.en.html", "rb")), ".doc-title a")`, it got 13 elements.

Comment: @xwhitelight thanks for this. Now I find very puzzling the following. This works `html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(url("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/index_include.en.html", "rb")), ".doc-title a"), "href")` and this doesn't `html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(url(year_urls1[1], "rb")), "doc_title a"), "href")`. Any idea why? It's just the same, in theory right?

Comment: First of all, I recommend using `%>%` operator instead. To your situation, I recommend debugging or simply printing `year_urls1[1]` before `read_html()`. Maybe something you did is wrong before. Make sure your code is right because both of your code lines in the post and the comment have syntax errors.

Comment: I tried `html_nodes(read_html(url(year_urls1[1], "rb")), ".doc-title a")`, it works fine too.

Comment: @xwhitelight thanks. I still cannot compute it when using `year_urls1[1]`, kind of a mistery to me