# How to add headers to an iterative script for web scraping with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, get, http-headers, httr

I have a series of functions to scrape user review data from trustpilot.com. When running the script I eventually get the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.
```

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690914/web-scraping-the-iis-based-website) I suspect that my script is generating too many requests without headers. My challenge is I am iterating through a list of URLs as my script scrapes the data, and I'm unsure how to add headers to each request.

```
# set up environment
library(tidyverse)  
library(rvest)    
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(httr)

# get the total/last page number from a trustpilot.com first page
# example output: 418 for 'travelocity.com'
get_review_last_page <- function(review_page){
  review_last_page_number <- review_page %>%
    html_nodes('.pagination_paginationEllipsis__4lfLO+ .pagination-link_item__mkuN3') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    strtoi()
}

# get author's review count
get_review_count <- function(review_page) {
  review_page %>%
  html_elements('span.typography_weight-regular__TWEnf') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  # remove unwanted data that is not a review count
  str_subset(pattern = "\\d\\sreview", negate = FALSE) %>%
  parse_number() %>%
  strtoi() %>%
  unlist()
}

# get the star ratings
get_review_ratings <- function(review_page) {
  review_page %>%
  html_elements('.styles_reviewHeader__iU9Px img') %>%
  html_attr("alt") %>%
  parse_number() %>%
  strtoi() %>%
  unlist()
}

# get review date and time
get_review_datetime <- function(review_page) {
  review_page %>%
  html_elements('.styles_datesWrapper__RCEKH time') %>%
  html_attrs() %>%
  map(1) %>%
  ymd_hms() %>%
  as.POSIXct(origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00') %>%
  unlist()
}

# combine everything into one tibble
build_data_table <- function(review_page, company_name){
  reviews_df <- tibble(
    review_count = get_review_count(review_page),
    rating = get_review_ratings(review_page),
    dtg = get_review_datetime(review_page)
  )
  # tag each data item with company name
  reviews_df %>%
    mutate(company = company_name) %>%
    select(company, review_count, rating, dtg)
}

# wrap data collection into one function call
get_review_data_from_url <- function(url, company_name){
  review_page <- read_html(url)
  build_data_table(review_page, company_name)
}

# the main script
scrape_review_data <- function(url, company_name){
  # read the first page
  review_first_page <- read_html(url)
  
  # get the total number of pages of reviews
  review_last_page_number <- (get_review_last_page(review_first_page))-1
  
  # generate the list of urls
  review_list_of_pages <- str_c(url, "?page=", 1:review_last_page_number)
  
  # apply all functions and write into one tibble
  cat("Scraping...\n")
  review_list_of_pages %>%
    map(get_review_data_from_url, company_name) %>%
    bind_rows()
}
scrape_page_url <- 'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.travelocity.com'
reviews_df <- scrape_review_data(scrape_page_url, "travelocity")
```

The script runs but eventually I get the 403 error. My challenge is figuring out where and how to add headers to the requests.

I have tried the following code:

```
temp_url <- 'https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.travelocity.com'
scrape_page_url <- GET(temp_url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Data project (myemail@email.com)'))
reviews_df <- scrape_review_data(scrape_page_url, "travelocity")
```

The error that follows is:

```
Warning message:
In stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

I have also tried embedding the GET request into the URL list generation:

```
review_list_of_pages <- str_c(GET((url, "?page=", 1:250), add_headers('user-agent' = 'Data project (my.email@email.com)'))
```

The error that follows is:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"  # generate the list of urls
  review_list_of_pages <- str_c(GET((url,"
```

My expected output is the completed dataframe with all the user reviews for each page for that company. When I choose a lower iteration size such as 1:10 or even 1:50 the script completes and I get the dataframe I'm looking for. In this particular example (travelocity.com) there are 417 pages of reviews; I am unsure as to what threshold creates the 403 error. I was able to run the script for another company (expedia.com) that has 288 pages without getting the 403 error.

Comment: also possible is that you are generating too many requests within a given time frame. Have you tried adding delays? For the headers debate, you replace read_html() calls with a call to  a single helper function which uses httr::GET and returns an HTMLDocument. You then add the headers there. Call that function, when needed elsewhere in code. Then you only need to make changes to that function when it comes to playing with headers etc.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, I'll take a look at those options.